# Access native feature of the platform

Tags: flutter

How do we access native feature of the platform in flutter?

For example: If we want to get the battery level of the phone then how can we get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Platform Channel` for this. Here is flutter's official documentation for this https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-kotlin-tab